# What month(s) does hajj take place in?

Tags: hajj, surat-al-baqarah

In surah baqarah allah says that the hajj is in the well known months. (2:197)

What does Allah mean by this? Because the hajj is held on specific hijri dates every year. Does it mean that we can perform hajj other than 8-13th dhul hijjah?

Comment: Can someone clarify? Can hajj be done in shawaal and dhul qadah?

Comment: Hajj is composed of various rituals. The state of Ihram can be entered in Shawal, Dhu al-Qa'dah or Dhu al-Hijjah. Whereas, for example, the rituals of the day of 'Arafah or the day of Nahr can only be observed on their specified days